# Optimization for iterating and plotting a matrix product and its elements?

Tags: plotting, matrix, manipulate, evaluation

I have an iterative matrix product of this type

$$
\begin{pmatrix}y_{n+1} \\ x_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}y_{n} \\ x_{n} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Since I didn't know how to do it, I explicitly wrote the product as 
`{A*yn + B*xn, C*yn + D*xn}` and evaluated it with the NestList construct

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Orbit[d, F, R, B, k, n, pt], 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> {600, 600}, ImagePadding -> 25, PlotRange -> Full],
 "map parameters",
 {{z, -0.7, "x0"}, -3, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/100},
 {{w, -2.2, "y0"}, -3, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/100},
 {{d, .012, "d"}, 0, 1, .001, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/100},
 {{F, 0.044, "E"}, 0, 1, .001, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/10},
 {{R, 0.76, "R"}, 0, 1, .001, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/10},
 {{B, 6.157, "B"}, 0, 10, .001, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/10},
 {{k, 10.04, "C"}, 0, 50, .001, Appearance -> "Open", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, AnimationRate -> 1/10},
 Button[Style["randomize parameters", 9], {z, w, d, F, R, B, k} = 
   RandomReal /@ {{0, 20}, {0, 20}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 
      10}, {0, 50}}, ImageSize -> 125, Appearance -> "FramedPalette"],
 "\n number of iterates n",
 {{n, 100, ""}, {100, 200, 1000, 5000, 100000, 500000}},
 {{pt, {z, w}, ".."}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, FrameMargins -> 0,
 Initialization :> (Orbit = 
    Compile[{d, F, R, B, k, {n, _Integer}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, 
     NestList[
      Module[{t = 
          B - k/(1 + #1[[1]] #1[[1]] + #1[[2]] #1[[2]])}, {1/
            4 (5 F + 
             2 #1[[1]] (-1 + 2 R Cos[t] + 
                9 d R Sin[t]) + \[Sqrt]((F - 2 #1[[1]])^2 + 
                8 R #1[[1]] Sin[
                  t] (9 d F - 
                   6 d #1[[1]] + (1 + 27 d^2) R #1[[1]] Sin[t]))) + 
          1/(2 R #1[[1]]) Csc[
            t] (-F + 2 #1[[1]] - 
             12 d R #1[[1]] Sin[
               t] - \[Sqrt]((F - 2 #1[[1]])^2 + 
                8 R #1[[1]] Sin[
                  t] (9 d F - 
                   6 d #1[[1]] + (1 + 27 d^2) R #1[[1]] Sin[t]))) #1[[
            2]], -R #1[[1]] Sin[t] + (#1[[2]]/(4 #1[[1]])) ( 
            F + 2 #1[[
               1]] (-1 - 2 R Cos[t] + 
                9 d R Sin[t]) + \[Sqrt]((F - 2 #1[[1]])^2 + 
                8 R #1[[1]] Sin[
                  t] (9 d F - 
                   6 d #1[[1]] + (1 + 27 d^2) R #1[[1]] Sin[t])))}] &,
       pt, n]])]
```

Here is a sample image showing my code output

[image: code output]

I would also like to store the value of each element at every step, since I also didn't know how to do it I made a different program that first makes all the iterations and then I evaluate each element.

```
    Orbit = NestList[
              Module[{t = o[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]]}, {#1[[1]] A[#1[[1]],#1[[2]],t] + #1[[2]] B[#1[[1]],#1[[2]],t], #1[[1]] C[#1[[1]],#1[[2]],t] + #1[[2]] D[#1[[1]],#1[[2]],t]}] &,
               pt, n]])]
 A[#1[[1]],#1[[2]],t]/. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ %
```

Since my function is composed by many trigonometric functions I would like to ensure that the computer is using as many digits as possible. Is this done by default by Mathematica or I must add something else?

I know that a more efficient method should exist, but I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: Your posted code includes symbols o,A,C,D in the complied function, but they are not defined anywhere. You should avoid using C and D anyway as they are built-in functions.

Comment: With A,B,C,D im refering to the matrix elements shown in the first image, those are functions of the variables #[[1]],#[[2]], o. o is also another function that depends on those variables, and it appears as the argument of the trigonometric functions that compose each element [A,B,C,D]. 

Each matrix element is a very long function so I replaced them with those symbols to avoid text cluttering.

Comment: Maybe you can use some simpler, shorter functions to make a working example. It's really hard to optimise code just by looking at it - people really need something they can paste into Mathematica and play with. BTW you can use `Dot` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I edited my post to add the full code.

Comment: The square rooted term in the function appears 3 times and is quite complicated. It will be faster if you compute it just once like you do with `t`. Other than that I can't see any obvious optimisations.

Comment: Regarding numerical precision - when you use `Compile` you are always using machine precision. Outside of compiled code you can use exact arithmetic or arbitrary precision (see the tutorial *tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers* for example), but it will be much slower.